# randomly fill 2d array with arrayList words

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck on my wordSearch program. I'm trying to fill the 2d array with words from my `arrayList` which has been entered by the user. Can anybody help me?

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
public class WordSearchPuzzle
{
    private char[][] puzzle ;
    private ArrayList<String> puzzleWords ;
    private int letterCount = 0 ;
    private int gridDimensions;

    public WordSearchPuzzle(ArrayList<String> userSpecifiedWords)
    {
        this.puzzleWords = userSpecifiedWords ;

    }

    private void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size() ; i++){
            letterCount = puzzleWords.size() + letterCount ;
        }
        gridDimensions = letterCount * 2;
        puzzle = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions] ;
    }


    public void fill() {

        int i, j, row, col;
        boolean added;


        for (i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size(); i++) {
            row = (int) (Math.random() * this.gridDimensions);
            col = (int) (Math.random() * this.gridDimensions);
            added = false;
            ???
```

Comment: Just a tip: tag your question with the according language tag as it won't get too much views otherwise.  Have you tried anything yet? What's not working?

Comment: thanks man I'l do that in future.I'm just unsure how I'm going to add the words randomly to the 2d array.The words dont have to be interlinking or traversing diagonally just up or down

Answer (score 0):

The `Random` class has a [`nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method, and the `List` interface has a `size()` method.

Generate a random index between 0 and the size of the list, and get the word at the resulting index from the list.

Comment: That will get me a random word from the arrayList I'm trying to fill the 2d array randomly with characters from the words from inside the arrayList

Comment: The iterate through your words and collect each character into a Set<Character>, then transform this set into an array, and apply the same technique with the array. If you want a useful answer, try to write a clear question. Your question doesn't explain what you want to do clearly.